# What are these things in Elon Musk's tweeted Starship video?

Tags: spacex, identify-this-object, spacex-starship

I don't understand what I'm looking at in the video of this [Elon Musk tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1176007759751499776). The text says:

> Just leaving SpaceX Starship build site in Boca

These are reminiscent of funhouse mirrors. What are these things exactly? If they're rocket parts, where on the rocket do they go?

Screenshots (click for full size):

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Only a guess, those are curved panels covering the root / hinges of the fins, creating a smooth aerodynamic fillet, protecting hinge's actuators from heat, housing wirings, tubings, maybe even fuel line from upper tank to engines ( don't know which tank is on top, methane or oxygen)

Comment: @qqjkztd I just ran across this: https://youtu.be/lRbKZqg5W-I?t=101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to The Man Himself

> Raceway & flap hinge aero covers

[image]

More [here](https://www.humanmars.net/2019/09/possible-cover-for-spacex-starship-mk-1.html), more speculative. Doesn't match current planned configuration?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay I'm getting the picture now, thank you!